Post returns 404 after changing the permalink using post_type_link
I have a custom post type named Manufacturer(manufacturer) created using JetEngine. I have also created a taxonomy named Manufacturer Categories(manufacturer-categories). Now what I want is when I have a post named Michelin, under the Truck taxonomy, I want it to look like mysite.com/manufacturers/truck/michelin where manufacturers is an additional string I add in the url. I have achieved this by using the code below using post_type_link :
function add_my_rewrites() {
    add_rewrite_tag( 'manufacturers', '([^/]+)' );
}

function manufacturer_post_type_link($link, $post) {
        if ( 'manufacturers' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
            $manufacturer = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'manufacturer-categories');
            $manufacturerslug = $manufacturer[0]->slug;
            $link = str_replace('manufacturers', 'manufacturers/'.$manufacturerslug, $link);
        }
        return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'manufacturer_post_type_link', 1, 3);

however, when I go to the post using the new permalink, I get 404, but when I visit the old permalink, the post is there. I tried adding the rewrite_tag but it did not help. Where and what did I miss? Really appreciate the help.

*** I'm not familiar with JetEngine, but this is what to do with core WordPress; maybe it will help. ***
The post_type_link filter only tells WordPress to change the URL in links, it doesn't inform WordPress on how the page is requested:

Filters the permalink for a post of a custom post type.

To have the CPT permalink include the taxonomy term, set the rewrite parameter of the CPT to array( 'slug' => 'manufacturers/%manufacturer-categories%' ), and then adjust the callback for the post_type_link filter to replace %manufacturer-categories% with the term's slug.

hey man, JetEngine does not accept an array for the rewrite slug, does this mean I have to register again the CPT and there the rewrite option with the array parameter?

Looks like there may be a "Rewrite Slug" field in the Advanced settings for the CPT? Try setting that field to manufacturers/%manufacturer-categories%.

it just treats it as plain text though like this https://www.mysite.com/manufacturers/%manufacturer-categories%/durapack-python-2/

Please add a new section to your question with the changes to the post_type_link filter callback.
